# Differences between function visibility features in Libraries

Tags: library, visibility, libraries

Function visibility in Libraries seems to provide different set of features than in ordinary contracts.
I think that also depends on the library type - if it is externally deployed or if it's code is inherited in the contract that is using it.
I am looking for a defined set of rules for this, I couldn't find any documentation that covers this topic.

Comment: This might help 
https://jeancvllr.medium.com/solidity-tutorial-all-about-libraries-762e5a3692f9

Answer (score 0):

So with libraries, as soon as you declare any state variables or functions as public or external, the library will become an external library.

External libraries live in separate contracts, and there is a step during compilation where you must input the addresses to link the libraries to your contracts using them.

Internal libraries are included in the deployed bytecode of your contract, and essentially live inside of it.

Libraries are by default internal until you declare something to be public or external.

These are also referred to as Embedded Libraries and Linked Libraries.